# Dataframe subsets based on date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to analize some data but would like to separate them "automatically" into different subsets. It is a data frame with heads "date", "time" and "heartRate". I'd like to create the subsets by different day. Have already tried

`data.loc[df['date']==2022-02-06]`

but returns the next error:

`SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers`

Any ideas how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed quotes:

```
#              HERE ---v----------v
data.loc[df['date'] == '2022-02-06']
```

Else you are trying to subtract an integer from an octal:

```
>>> 2022-02
...
SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers

>>> 2022-0o2
2020
```